# Flash playing video half speed, audio at normal speed

Tags: video, flash

I have a swf on a web page playing an flv.  On the server it plays the video at half speed and the audio at normal speed.  When I play the same swf on my local machine everything is played correctly.  Here is the object code on the page:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,40,0,0"
width="640" height="480" id="myMovieName">
<param name="movie" value="/App_Flash/EdandMike2_VP6.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="bgcolor" value="#FFFFFF" />
<embed src="/App_Flash/EdandMike2_VP6.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" width="640" height="480"
name="myMovieName" align="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer">
</embed>
</object>
```

Comment: Can you post links to the server(s) you're trying this on? It would probably help people diagnose the problem if they could actually attempt to load it on both pages and analyze the source, HTTP headers, etc.

Comment: I had some unrelated problems and had to take down the SWF's temporarily from the site.  When I get them back up I will.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first off, the playback issues really won't have much to do with your embed code, although it does raise the question of why you're targeting FP6. If it's not a client requirement, I'd use a more modern version of flashplayer.

I think preloading / buffering more of the flv is a good solution if this is a progressive-download video. From what I've read this seems to be a problem with progressive flv's, so if you could switch to streaming, it may fix the problem. I've also read that flv's, in particular have problems with audio / video syncing, so if you can upgrade to flash player 9, which supports mov, h.264, and mp4.

Comment: I had copied the object tag from another source and just entered in my own dimensions and source file.  I don't have any reason to be targeting version 6 so I am going to try updating it to either 8 or 9 and see what happens.  Good suggestion.  Thanks.

Comment: Also... that's the old school default flash embed, it won't fix your problem, but it might be worthwhile to use a newer method like swfobject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a streaming issue. If you're loading the FLV externally (it's not embedded in the SWF file), make sure you've set up a network stream and a buffer time. Otherwise, the FLV may not be loading fast enough to keep up.

Adobe has an article on [playing back external FLV files dynamically](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001569.html) that covers these topics.

You can also explicitly [preload the FLV](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/8/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00001569.html).

Answer (score 0):

**Possibilities to try out:** 
1) Try with some other FLV video and check in local and remote server
2) Use existing FLV Web based Player to play the flv to make sure the swf which you have works fine . try this flv player http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/

There might be a case where the swf loads flv has some Action script loading issues or some relative/absolute path issues. Share the result once tried it out.

Comment: The SWF works fine on a different server with the same flv.  Its only on this particular server that there are problems.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a problem i had with a video file that originally came from someones cellphone. The only tool that would encode it right (audio + video synched up on all machines) as an flv was [ffmpegx](http://www.ffmpegx.com/).

If you're on windows/linux you might want to look into [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) or [mencoder/mplayer](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).

Comment: The flv itself plays fine on other systems. The swf with the flv also plays fine on other servers.  It's only this server in particular that exhibits this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I embedded a mov file into a swf and also an flv. You have to change the frame rate of your new file to match the frame rate if the video you're converting. Flash defaulted my frame rate to 12fps and my movie was done at 30fps, causing the video to appear to run at about half the speed of the audio. Changing the frame rate before exporting the movie fixed it for me perfectly.